# google finance getprices URL works via browser but not working since 03 august 2018

Tags: php, google-finance, google-finance-api

google finance getprices URL works via browser but not working since 03 august 2018
any solution why

I have checked programatically also in PHP

```
<?php
$arrContextOptions=array(
            "ssl"=>array(
                "verify_peer"=>false,
                "verify_peer_name"=>false,
            ),
        );  

$URL = 'https://finance.google.com/finance/getprices?f=d,c,v,k,o,h,l&p=60&x=NSE&q=ITC&i=60;
$filecontent = file_get_contents( $URL , false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));


print_r($filecontent);
?>
```

Generally this give me TimeStamp,OPEN, HIGH, LOW, Close, Volume data in text format but this is not working now.

Comment: Not working via browser for me either. Always display "We're sorry...
... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now." - from any device for me.